# MySQL 2 foreign keys to the same primary key

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables; a task table and an employee table.

A task is created by an employee and maintains the id of the employee that creates it as creator_id.

A task is assigned to an employee and maintains the id of the employee it is assigned to as responsible_id.

The creator of the task and the employee it is assigned to can be different people.

How do I write a select statement that allows me to display the full names of both the employee that created the task and the employee that is assigned to it.

I think it *might* look something like this:

```
SELECT Task.Description, Employee1.name, Employee2.name
FROM Task, Employee Employee1, Employee Employee2
WHERE Task.creator_id = Employee1.id
AND Task.responsible_id = Employee2.id;
```

I have tried variations of this but it either returns errors or hits the memory limit.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you update the question with a small sample data set that causes the errors?

Answer (score 0):

From your description the query is correct but you should consider rewriting it to use explicit ANSI joins:

```
SELECT Task.Description, Employee1.name, Employee2.name
FROM Task
JOIN Employee Employee1 ON Task.creator_id = Employee1.id
JOIN Employee Employee2 ON Task.responsible_id = Employee2.id;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b26f/1)